# How is the Dragon's damage calculated in Rogue Legacy?

Tags: rogue-legacy

The Dragon class seems to use the same attack for the regular attack, which calculates damage based on Strength, and the special attack, which calculates damage based on Intelligence. Is the Dragon's attack damage based on Strength, Intelligence, or some combination?

Answer (score 8):

The Dragon's attack is based on his Intelligence stat.  Every attack he does is magical, so what you want is lots and lots of Magic Attack Up upgrades.  Since he recovers MP so fast, it's easy enough to always have full MP.

Comment: Are you sure? I increased my Strength and my damage went up, if i recall correctly, so it may be a combination?

Comment: I will double-check when I get home, but I'm pretty sure it's based entirely off of their Magic.

Answer (score 5):

I dug through the code to find an answer to this, and it turns out both buttons for the dragon class do the exact same thing, which is to call `CastSpell()` *(normally only done when pressing the 'spell' button)*.

Within `CastSpell()`, the total damage is only affected by `PlayerObj.TotalMagicDamage` - which depends only on your Magic-Up *("Intelligence")* skill and any Magic-Up fairy chests you've opened - and some class/spell-related constants.

Thus, increasing your Attack-Up *("Strength")* will not increase the dragon's attack damage at all; only Magic-Up will.

Comment: The code, for anyone who cares, is located at `RogueCastle.PlayerObj.InputControls()` and `RogueCastle.PlayerObj.CastSpell()`.